# jquery unwrap - unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple function that wrap or unwrap the logo from a bootstrap navbar according to the screen size.

Basically, on mobile the logo is on the left, on desktop is in the middle.

Here's the function:

var checkLogo;

```
checkLogo = function() {
  var logo, logoId, w;
  w = window.innerWidth;
  logoId = $('#logo').length;
  logo = "<li id='logo'></li>";
  if (w < 768) {
    if (logoId !== 0) {
      $('.navbar-brand').unwrap(logo);
      return $('.navbar-brand').insertAfter('.navbar-toggle');
    }
  } else {
    if (logoId === 0) {
      $('.navbar-brand').wrap(logo);
      return $('#logo').insertAfter('.navbar-nav li:nth-child(2)');
    }
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  return checkLogo();
});

$(window).resize(checkLogo);
```

As I said, the function is very straight forward and it actually works.

The problem I've got is when unwrapping the element. It still works, but i get this error and I don't understand why.

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: (…)

Do you have any suggestion?

If i remove the id, the error disappears, but ideally i need to be able to append a specific ID as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's [`unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) only takes one single argument

> A selector to check the parent element against. If an element's parent
>   does not match the selector, the element won't be unwrapped.

Passing in HTML like `<li id='logo'></li>` is not a valid selector to check the wrapping elements against, if you wanted to make sure that you only unwrap that element, you'd do

```
$('.navbar-brand').unwrap('#logo');
```